# Getting Sqlite Error code 14 while running an phonegap app on Device?

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

Please help to fine the error. 
What i am doing is i had created an service in starting the service as soon as app starts and at the same time trying to load the html file . I had created the  service just to upload the data to server. So when i try to run the app on the emulator it runs without error but when i try to run it on the device it give this error:

```
02-25 12:38:33.151: I/Database(3039): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at source line 25467
```

can anyone tell where i am wrong.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Sqlite error code 14 is unable to open  the database  error.

Comment: refer this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316191/android-sqlite-returned-error-code-14